# imac: add vector layer in python

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer

I used the following line to try and add a vector shapefile to my qgis map, though it gives me "invalid layer" errors. Does anyone see something I don't?

```
iface.addVectorLayer(r"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Wells/WD/Shapefiles/wd_14/wd14.shp","test","ogr")
```

I'm fairly new to python- do I have to define a variable before running this command? *on Mac OSX

Comment: your layer isn't right.. first of all it's not a complete path (perhaps it should start with c:\\Users\\...) and secondly it's full of escape chars.. either double your slashes or put an r in front to make it a raw string. Read about strings, quotes and slashes here https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html , that should put you on the right path.

Comment: I should mention that the file path is on mac, if that makes a difference. I'll try the suggested changes- thank you!

Comment: It shouldn't, strings are strings, that's one of the beauties of python - it's the same on all platforms. I'm not familiar with Linux or Mac so perhaps the path is right.. I'm looking at it from a windows point of view, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905880/how-do-i-create-a-file-path-on-a-mac which says the path should use a forward slash '/' which isn't the same as a backslash '\', the forward slash is not an escape sequence initiator.

Comment: I added the suggested changes above- still no luck but I'll update with any progress. Should be the simplest python command so I'm hoping this isn't the first roadblock

Comment: What error message do you get? Perhaps more lines of code would give some more context.

Comment: Layer is not valid: The layer /Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Wells/WD/Shapefiles/wd_14/wd14.shp is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

Comment: Can it be added manually? Perhaps the shapefile is corrupt. Is that path correct for your filesystem?

Comment: yes it can, I checked the path name and it seems to match- it appears in OSX as:

Macintosh HD > Users > pgcseismolab > Desktop > jaden_pgc_archive > Wells > WD >Shapefiles >wd_14 . 

From what I've read the "Macintosh HD" is replaced with a slash

would "test" or "ogr" be the issue ?

Comment: This works manually, though it is going to be a repetetive task as I have over 20 shapefiles to load each time I start a new project. More than that, I'm keen on becoming more familiar with these types of automation to save time down the road

Comment: You could check if the process finds the layer using os.path.exists (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python) but apart from that I'm out of ideas, your code looks fine according to http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

Comment: ok I'll try this, thanks so much for the assistance

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhh

The filename is wd_14 rather than wd14... problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

I missed an underscore in the filename wd_14. Using os.pathexists, I determined that there was an issue with the file name:

```
os.path.exists(r"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Wells/WD/Shapefiles/wd_14/wd14.shp")
```

False

Then, using this code I was able to properly load my layer:

```
iface.addVectorLayer(r"/Users/pgcseismolab/Desktop/jaden_pgc_archive/Wells/WD/Shapefiles/wd_14/wd_14.shp","test","ogr")
```

Comment: It's great that you got it working but that answer is a little brief and might be subject to derision. Can you edit your answer and put in some of your code to show how you got it working please. Did you end up using os.path.exists()? I would like to know if that works as advertised on a Mac platform... there is also os.path.isdir() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077424/python-os-path-exists-vs-os-path-isdir which is useful, exists is True whether the object is a folder or file so you need to test if the target is a file or folder that exists.

Comment: yes I did- that was very useful in finding the root cause of the problem. I will certainly make more use of the os.path options with OSX